# Easy test to see if two columns of numbers are correlated?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test

I have a simple set of data that looks like

```
key     thingID     countOfThing   NumberBadThingsHappen
1       xxx         64             200
2       xxx         20             10
```

What are some applicable tests to see if `countOfThing` and `NumberBadThingsHappen` share any type of relationship?  The first two columns serve to uniquely identify the last two.  I don't anticipate this being a panacea for any real analysis, just looking for a place to start.  Feel free to edit I've tagged this incorrectly.

Comment: I would suggest changing your strategy from *testing* to *exploration.* Start by summarizing and visualizing your data. A natural beginning to visualization (for the purposes of identifying relationships) is a scatterplot. (When you're still at the stage of wondering what type of relationship two variables might have, formal statistical tests give misleading results. Search the literature for "data snooping" and ["data dredging"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging).)

Comment: One of the bad things about learning something on your own is, sometimes you don't know what things are called!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Note there are different types of correlation (Pearson and Spearman), and just because Pearson $\rho=0$ doesn't mean there is no relationship ([there are nice examples on wikipedia for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation)). Hence, as suggested in the comments, you should make a scatterplot using the two variables.

Then you can compute the correlation coefficient that seems most appropriate.

Another quick way to test for dependence is to run a linear regression (OLS) of one variable on the other. The t test of the slope coefficient tests for a significant relationship. The sign of the slope parameter will be identical to that of the correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason not to use [Pearson's correlation](http://www.statisticshowto.com/articles/what-is-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient/) for quick analyse? And do some simple eplonatory analysis with data visualization (scatterplots etc).